# How to convert HTML tags to HTML in php

Tags: php, html

I am using tinymce editor for description. This is my html

> He is charged with **determining** the best ways for us to visually represent our firm.

[image: Like this]

But it is displaying as it is at the front end. How can I convert it to HTML using php? I am doing this.

```
<p><?=$key['description'];?></p>
```

Comment: Did you escape your brackets? Because it should display as usual

Comment: nope i didn't do it

Comment: @AliZia have you included editor's css file in frontend

Comment: How do you input this `HTML´? As direct text? You should not enter pure `HTML` in a whyswyg editor... You should enable the `source` or `code` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `html_entity_decode($key['description'])` and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Either you are entering pure `HTML` in the editor or saving the `HTML` with `htmlentities` to the database which are both use cases. You should solve that instead decoding the output. This allows misuse of the editor and can cause harm to your website if used publicly

Answer (score -1):

you want to display HTML content in your PHP Page . If that is the case, 
use that code inside the `<xmp>` tag.

Ex :
`<xmp>` `<p><?=$key['description'];?></p> </xmp>`

For better view , you can use SyntaxHighlighter ,rainbow packages

Links:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-add-syntax-highlighting-to-any-project--net-21099
  https://craig.is/making/rainbows

Hope it helps you !!

Thanks.

Comment: wrapping input from an editor will cause broken `HTML` for sure